# Custom response of default operations of ApiPlatform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to customize the default operations of API Platform.
I read the documentation of API Platform on the custom controller and operation, but I don't really understand, someone can explain me please ?

#### Context

I have two entities : **User** and **Car** related by a relation **ManyToMany**.

**User.php**

```
#[ApiResource()]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    ...
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Car::class, mappedBy: 'users')]
    private Collection $cars;
    ...
}
```

**Car.php**

```
#[ApiResource()]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CarRepository::class)]
class Car
{
   ...
   #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'cars')]
   private Collection $users;
   ...
}
```

With ApiPlatform I can do all actions (Get, Post, Put...).

#### Question

When a user is login, he can use the API, when he try a GET on `/api/cars`, this return all cars.
How can I do for return only cars who are related to the user ?

Thanks to read me, have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Check out API Platform documentation about CurrentUserExtension at : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/. Should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer on :
[Symfony 6 Api Platform Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299964/symfony-6-api-platform-extension/75321571#75321571)
It almost the same usecase.

Comment: I tried your answer, but this didn't work for me , I have this error : "This route does not aim to be called" like if he don't want to take my uriTemplate: "/cars/my-cars"

Comment: Because it is on user side so it cant be /cars/my-cars but "users/my-cars"